# Vim - Skipping lines in visual selection

Tags: vim

In visual mode, how can I select an interval of lines but skip over certain lines?

For example:

```
1 Hello
2 World
3 Foo
4 Bar
```

How can I select lines 1 and 4 without selecting lines 2 and 3?  Is it even possible in Vim?

Looking for using it at vifm too.

Comment: I might be completely wrong here, but I think the visual modes only support contiguous regions of each kind. What do you want to do with the lines after they’ve been selected?

Comment: Vim doesn’t support non-contiguous selections (although I suppose some people would consider Visual Block mode to be non-contiguous). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I was really in doubt if it was supported. I was just trying to find a better way to copy/yank/del multiple lines without the answer of @user2657794

Comment: And for using it on vifm, selecting between files/folders to some operation

Comment: Okay, if you don’t want to use commands, I suppose [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) is something that people use.

Comment: It's not about commands.. I already tried this plugin, not the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to copy/yank/del multiple nonconsecutive lines you can use named registers.

You do this using several selections:

Select first portion and yank/del using `"ay`/`"ad`. This will yank/del to register `a`. You can use any letter you want.

For every next selection use uppercase register name: `"Ay`/`"Ad`, this will append selection to the register contents instead of overwriting it.

After that you paste it where you need: `"ap`. Or if you need it in system clipboard: `:let @*=@a`.

To inspect the contents of the register `a` use `:reg a`. `:reg` will show you the contents of all registers.

Comment: assuming that @bdesham is correct (vim doesn't support non-contiguous selections), this is the best answer. Very fast and pratical.

Answer (score 2):

- [multiselect](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=953) allows to select non-contiguous regions and execute Ex and normal mode commands on them. Only works line-wise, not on arbitrary selections!
- My [RepeatableYank plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4238) makes yanking multiple ranges / selections easier because you can use `.` to repeat, and don't have to supply the `"A` uppercase register name to append all the time.

Comment: multiselect uses mouse, not my way. But your plugin is very interesting, going to test it on my vim. Not the best answer because I needed one who works on vifm too.

Comment: You can also use `<Enter>` in visual mode with multiselect; mouse is just an alternative.